# In the SQL Server, how can i check if the column value contains only zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Assumptions: considering Sample to be the db and Column_Name to be the table.

Sample input :

```
Column_Name
12345
000
00
00000
```

Output:

```
Column_Name
000
00
00000

Select * from Sample.Column_Name where  Column_Name like '[0]+'
```

The above piece of code dint work
What is the right approach for this?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Varchar is the data type

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008? It's been completely unsupported for over 2 years now; long past time to have completed any upgrade paths.

Comment: v18 is the version of SSMS, to find the version of SQL SERVER do `select @@version`

Comment: Version is 2017

Comment: To check if it contains only zeros, it doesn't matter if it's one zero or two zeroes

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I misread your question as "only one zero".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact solution should be :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Sample.Column_Name 
WHERE  Column_Name = REPLICATE('0', LEN(Column_Name ));
```

Assuming that Column_Name is a VARCHAR datatype column

Comment: Will also accept trailing spaces. `REPLICATE('0', LEN(Column_Name + 'a') - 1)`

Comment: I was supposing the database data quality is perfect... Of course it is what I usually do for all my DB's. If this is not the case, a simple TRIM will do the job to remove trainling and leading spaces...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not like` with wildcards like this:

```
where column_name not like '%[^0]%'
```

To be sure there is one zero:

```
where column_name not like '%[^0]%' and column_name like '%0%'
```

You can also use `replace()`:

```
where replace(column_name, '0', '') = ''
```

Or even `try_convert()`:

```
where try_convert(int, column_name) = 0
```

However, that would also accept `-0`, `+0`, and spaces.

Comment: The replace version will also return an empty string (if found in the column.)

Comment: try_convert will also accept  `'+0'`, `'   0 '`

Comment: @jarlh . . . True.  I thought I covered that with the first example though.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from Sample.Column_Name where isnumeric(Column_Name) = 1 and cast(Column_Name as int) == 0
```

Comment: Tq ,but if there's a value say 1000 this will also be in the output, I want only values which has zeros to appear in the op.

Comment: Remove the first % symbol

Comment: But then `'01'` would still match, @theunknownSAI . The above would match *any* string that *contains* the character `'0'`, not a string that is made up of only the character `'0'`.